# Using other Network Interface for apt

Tags: ubuntu, interface, proxy, apt

my situation is as follows:

I am connected with eth0 to our DataCenter. There is a proxy for going out to the internet,  but really restricted.
With wlan0 i am in our non-proxy enviroment, where i have no access to our DataCenter.

My Problem: I dont want to use apt-get over the eth0 interface, because our internal apt mirror does not support my local ubuntu version and it works as designed, that i get an network unreachable error.
I want to use apt-get install over the wlan0 interface, because there is an unrestricted connection to the internet. But without take the et0 down, because i dont want to restart all my sessions to our Datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sh
# Add a new namespace called test_ns
ip netns add aptwifi

# Set test to use eth0, after this point eth0 is not usable by programs
# outside the namespace
ip link set wlan0 netns aptwifi

# Bring up eth0 inside test_ns
ip netns exec aptwifi ip link set wlan0 up

# Use dhcp to get an ipv4 address for eth0
ip netns exec aptwifi dhclient wlan0

# Ping google from inside the namespace
ip netns exec aptwifi apt update
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface